# Why XAML button can't invoke argumentless function

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have function in create.cs

```
    private void FillGrid()
    {
        ClearingEntities CE = new ClearingEntities();
        var Accountss = CE.Accounts;
        DataGrid1.ItemsSource = Accountss.ToList();
    }
```

I invoke this function from other ***.cs*** files just writing **FillGrid();** without any arguments

but from xaml in button Click="FillGrid" gives error

**click** auto generated functions have

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

I don't want insert those ***object sender, RoutedEventArgs e*** arguments

if I insert those to my function's arguments then other calling should be changed 
to

**FillGrid([argument],[argument]);**

note: *it is not event handling function just fill data stuff*

how to call FillGrid() from xaml? without changing create.cs

Comment: Does it work if you call Button_click ?

Comment: in .cs other function call works but in xaml program doesn't evens start

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible example with your issue?

Comment: You can try something like that.  `private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => FillGrid();` For event handling you can not get rid of those arguments but you can kinda "redirect" to you method....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011869/handling-a-buttons-click-event-in-xaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the way Button Event's work. 
Read more about `EventHandler` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler?view=netframework-4.8)

Why don't you just use this:

```
<Button Click="FillGridClicked" />

//sender = button, RoutedEventArgs = arguments of that event
private void FillGridClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FillGrid();
}
```

Every `ClickEventHandler` needs these arguments as it is a custom delegate defined that way. If you really want to emit this you need to extend the button and create a custom click handler for yourself. (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565695/extending-wpf-button-to-store-data-in-a-new-property) for example)